# Angular 5: Subscription isn't triggered on next value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

When a next value is pushed towards a Subject, the Subscription in the parent component isn't triggered (it does when I change the Subject to a BehaviorSubject which I can't use because there's no default value).

**option.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-option',
  templateUrl: './option.component.html'
})
export class OptionComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() httpHeader;

    period: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(){}

    setPeriod(period: string){
        this.period.next(period);
        console.log('Next period: ' + period);
    }
}
```

**option.component.html**

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="periode" (ngModelChange)="setPeriod($event)">
    <span *ngFor="let option of httpHeader.option"><mat-radio-button [checked]="option.default" [value]="option.param" >{{ option.desc }}</mat-radio-button><br /></span>
</mat-radio-group>
```

---

Parent component:

**periodeomzet.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { httpService } from 'app/services/http.service';
import { OptionComponent } from 'app/units/option/option.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-periodeomzet',
    templateUrl: './periodeomzet.component.html',
    providers: [OptionComponent]
})
export class PeriodeomzetComponent implements OnInit {

    httpHeader: Object;
    subData: Subscription;
    subOptions: Subscription;
    period: string = 'period=d';

    constructor(
        private httpService: httpService,
        private option: OptionComponent
    ){}

    getReport(){        
        this.subData = this.httpService.getReport().subscribe((res: Response) => {
            this.httpHeader = res.json()['header'];
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.subOptions = this.option.period.subscribe(period => {
            console.log('subOptions subscription fired');

            this.period = period;
            this.getReport();
            // Do other stuff
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.subData.unsubscribe();
        this.subOptions.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

**periodeomzet.component.html**

```
<app-option [httpHeader]="httpHeader"></app-option>
```

I expect to see "subOptions fired" in the console when I change the selection of a radio button but it only shows "Next period: ...". Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Why are you accessing the child component via DI, rather than binding to an @Output or communicating via a service?

Comment: I'm not sure why I did it this way since I'm a beginner. If I let the two components communicatie via a service, how can they communicate to the same instance of the service if I have more than one component pairs? Can you show an example with @Output?

Comment: Did you try reading the docs? https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Guilty :) ......

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've implemented the EventEmitter + @ Output method and that works. This was completely new for me so thank you form pointing that out

Comment: I'd recommend some kind of structured tutorial to introduce you to these basics. The official Angular Tour of Heroes one might be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject components like you're doing. Instead, you need to reference the component and use `ViewChild` (or `ViewChildren`) in order to select it.

In your template, you can use

```
<app-option #option [httpHeader]="httpHeader"></app-option>
```

Then, in the period component:

```
@ViewChild('option') option: OptionComponent;
```

If you don't want to use the `#option` template syntax you can also select it based on the component class:

```
@ViewChild(OptionComponent) option: OptionComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added `#option` in the template, added `@ViewChild('option') option: OptionComponent;` above the constructor in and removed the provider from TS, but the property 'period' can't be read of undefined

Comment: @Rogier did you also remove the injection of `OptionComponent`?

Comment: I think I did. I removed `provider: [OptionComponent]` from the component decorator

Comment: @Rogier and you also removed it from the constructor?